# Bootstrapのfield.control-groupが干渉するせい？か、上手くcssが適応できませんでした

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

rails のslimとbootstrapを用いて 
webのフロントサイドの実装をしておりました。

field.control-groupの中に、11項目程の入力フォームがある 
アンケートフォームを作成しております。

以下のコードには2つしかありませんが、まだ、これが残り9つある状態です。

この実装でbootstrapのデザインがあたったフォームはつくれたのですが、 
入力フォーム間の感覚がほとんどなく、詰まった印象があります。

marginなどを変更し、入力フォーム間をあけようと、独自にcssを作成し、適用しようとしていたのですが、上手くいきませんでした。 
（css自体はあたっているのですが、field.control-groupが干渉するせいか、画面には反映されてませんでした。）

こういったケースではどうしたらいいでしょうか？

※やりたいこととしては、入力項目の間隔を広げたいです。

```
= form_for @user, url: user_path(@user), html: {multipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f|
  .field.control-group
    .col-sm-6
      = f.label :email, class: 'control-label'
    .col-sm-6
      = f.email_field :email, class: 'fld__input form-control'

  .field.control-group
    .col-sm-6
      = f.label :password
    .col-sm-6
      = f.password_field :password, class: 'fld__input form-control'
  .field.control-group

・
・
・
続く
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

間隔を広げたいのは上下方向、という理解で合っていますか？

おそらく、`.row`で`.col-xxx`を挟んでやるとうまくいく気がします。

### Form

```
= form_for @user, html: {multipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f|
  .row
    .field.control-group
      .col-sm-6
        = f.label :email, class: 'control-label'
      .col-sm-6
        = f.email_field :email, class: 'fld__input form-control'

  .row
    .field.control-group
      .col-sm-6
        = f.label :password
      .col-sm-6
        = f.password_field :password, class: 'fld__input form-control'
```

### CSS

```
.control-group {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

`.row`がないとマージンが機能しないのは確認しました。

以下のjsfiddleでも実行結果を確認できます。

https://jsfiddle.net/368g0612/

```css
.control-group {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <main role="main">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="new_user" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="field control-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="control-label" for="user_email">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="fld__input form-control" type="email" name="user[email]" id="user_email" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="field control-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="user_password">Password</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="fld__input form-control" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: 私の環境下でも動作を確認いたしました。ありがとうございます。cssの適応が苦手だったため、大変参考になりました。